# The minimum number of polynomial equations the components of linearly dependent vectors must satisfy

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinants, groebner-bases

**Context:**

Consider $m<n$ vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_m\in\mathbb{C}^n$ with complex components. We can study if they are linearly dependent by constructing the following matrices. First the $n\times m$ matrix $A=[v_1,\dotsc,v_m]$ and the $n\times n$ matrix $B = [A,w_1,\dotsc,w_r]$ where $w_1,\dotsc,w_r\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are $r=n-m$ arbitrary vectors. The vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ are linearly dependent if and only if $B$ is singular for every choice of $w_1,\dotsc,w_r$. Equivalently, if $\det B=0$. Expanding the determinant in minors we get
$$
\det B = \sum_{\alpha\in\mathcal{A}}q_\alpha(w_1,\dotsc,w_r)\det A_\alpha
$$
where $\mathcal{A}=\{1,\dotsc,n\}^{m}$, $A_\alpha$ is the submatrix of $A$ of size $m\times m$ with rows of $A$ marked in $\alpha\in\mathcal{A}$, and $q_\alpha$ are some polynomials in the components of $w_1,\dotsc,w_r$. Hence, to obtain $\det B=0$ for any $w_1,\dotsc,w_r$ one need to have $\det A_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha\in\mathcal{A}$. Correct me if I'm wrong (maybe I'm not counting correctly), but there are $\binom n m = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ equations of the form $\det A_\alpha=0$. However, the set of vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_m$ have  $nm$ (independent) components. Hence, for a set of $m$ vectors to be linearly dependent, their $nm$ components must satisfy $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ equations. It's easy to verify that for many pairs $n$, $m$ (for instance $n=6$ and $m=3$) there are more equations than possible variables.

**If these were arbitrary polynomials, it wouldn't be possible to get linearly dependent vectors in general for such pairs $n$, $m$; however linearly dependent vectors do exist.** Therefore, many of these polynomials must be dependent in some way. In fact, if we consider only $m\times m$ submatrices in which the chosen rows were consecutive in $A$, we obtain $n-m+1$ equations which are independent, since every one of them introduces a a new set of variables (a whole new row of $A$) with respect to the previous ones. However, it is not clear to me if there are more of equations from all possibilities which are independent too.

**Question**: In general, what is the least number of equations of the form $\det A_\alpha=0$ that the components of the set of vectors $v_1,\dotsc,v_m\in\mathbb{C}^n$ must satisfy?

Or equivalently how many equations of the form $\det A_\alpha=0$  are (algebraically) independent.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent" when referring to equations? The $\det A_\alpha$ are **linearly** independent (when the entries of $A$ are generic indeterminates), but they are usually not **algebraically** independent, as they satisfy [the Grassmann-Plücker relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_embedding#Grassmann%E2%80%93Pl%C3%BCcker_relations). Are you looking for a transcendence basis for the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by the $\det A_\alpha$s (where $A$ is an $n\times m$-matrix of generic indeterminates)? (I suspect the cluster algebraists know this well.)

Comment: I mean algebraically. If the whole set of $\text{det} A_\alpha$ satisfy the grassman plucker relations, I wonder what is the greatest amount of equations of the form $\text{det} A_\alpha=0$ we can consider until we obtain independent (algebraically)  equations for generic indeterminate in $A$? Great info, thanks!

Comment: If $A$ is a sufficiently generic $n \times m$-matrix, then the determinants $\det A_\alpha$ are the Plücker coordinates of the span of the columns of $A$. So your question is: how many of these coordinates are algebraically independent? That is, what is the dimension of the variety of all $m$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^n$ ? (Indeed, the Plücker coordinates form a coordinatization of this variety.) But this variety is called the Grassmannian $\operatorname{Gr}\left(n,m\right)$, and its dimension is known to be $m\left(n-m\right)$ (indeed, it is easy to see ...

Comment: ... that every sufficiently generic $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ corresponds to a reduced column echelon matrix $A$, and such a matrix has $m\left(n-m\right)$ degrees of freedom; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/598331/what-is-the-dimension-of-this-grassmannian for details). Hence, the number of algebraically independent $\det A_\alpha$ coordinates is $m\left(n-m\right)$. Of course, this does not mean that every collection of $\det A_\alpha$ coordinates is algebraically independent.

Comment: So much interesting ideas. I think I need to read this more carefully, but this is potentially what I was looking for.  Thanks for your time @darijgrinberg!

Comment: TeX note:  please use $\det A$ `$\det A$`, which spaces properly, rather than $\text{det} A$ `$\text{det} A$`, which does not.  (`\det` is pre-defined, but there is a general construction for this sort of thing called `\operatorname`; `\det` is essentially `\operatorname{det}`.)  I have edited accordingly.  I also deleted the self deprecation at the beginning of the question.

Comment: Couple of comments; because of the difference between projective space and affine space, you really want more more equation than what @darijgrinberg said. This is obvious when $m=1$: you want an equation for each coordinate. The other point to make is that if you want to write down enough equations to ensure linear dependency, you need all the ${n \choose m}$ equations: for any one of them, there is a matrix which has that minor non-zero and all other minors zero.

Comment: Thanks Hugh! Can you elaborate more on this projective vs affine issue and how is that related to the problem?